# How to change img-src CSP directive in create-react-app

Tags: reactjs

I am using the INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK=false variable in my create-react-app build and it's setting a CSP directive at build time (building on Heroku) for img-src of 'self' data:. I need to modify this to host profile pics coming in from the IDP i'm using, so that img-src directive needs to be changed.

How can I change this as part of the build process? Or should I override the whole CSP string with a meta tag in index.html? Is there a way to configure this on the build step as part of the heroku-postinstall command?

Comment: Perhaps `react-helmet` could help? https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet

Comment: thanks goto1, unfortunately this still didn't help.. i managed to get react-helmet to set the title in the header, but something in the build process still overrides the CSP directives.... ?